# OpenAm - iDP - Authentication fails when the user name contains characters

Tags: ldap, openam, idp, forgerock

We have user created in DS with a character (such as A && B) in their user name, but when they try to authenticate to an application protected by AM.

**Error Log:**
Échec de la connexion" "Not Available" XXXXX

User XXXXX exists in LDAP.

The following command

```
./ssoadm get-attr-defs -s sunIdentityRepositoryService -t Organization -u [adminID] -f [passwordfile] | grep sunIdRepoAttributeValidator > DATA_FILE
```

return:

```
sunIdRepoAttributeValidator=class=com.sun.identity.idm.server.IdRepoAttributeValidatorImpl
sunIdRepoAttributeValidator=minimumPasswordLength=8
```

Any suggestions please ?

Comment: What is the name of this user? I am sorry I did not understand the example.

Comment: The name of the user is B12345